# Java how to change alpha, hue, saturation and brightness into argb value?

Tags: java

If I have an alpha integer and three floats for hue, saturation and brightness, how can I convert them in the most compact way using a method into one argb value?

Edit: I know I can use HSBtoRGB, I have read through the java Color class  but it returns 255 for the alpha value eventhough I have my own custom value for alpha. In other words, I thought of a solution that I do not know how to do because I am not familiar with working with binary operators. How can you edit the alpha value of an argb value in a compact way?

Kind Regards,
Krush

Comment: Please provide an example of your code/whatever you have tried.  That will help us point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I agree with Aderis: read the docs.  After scanning the documentation, I think the HSBtoRBG() method is probably the best.  Then just OR the alpha value.

```
int alpha = ...
int arbg = Color.HSBtoRBG( ... ) | (alpha << 24);
```

You'll need to adjust this if your alpha is in a range other than 0..255.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Java Color class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html). The method you want is HSBtoRGB(). It returns an int, which is in the form where each byte is a different component.

If you think there should be a function for something, check the docs first before posting here. Took me 30 seconds to find it.